# Reload Data in TableView and group

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

i have a normal table view, and i want to reload the data and make de table separated with groups changing the tableview style to group,i was trying to use the method to give a title for each header its goes ok,but only if i init with it,not for change in runtime, is that possible,or i have to load another view?

```
    -(NSString *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section {
if(group){
    switch (section) { case 0: return @"A"; break; case 1: return @"B"; break; case 2: return @"C"; break; case 3: return @"D"; break; case 4: return @"E"; break; } }return nil;
    }
```

i try to put a boolean to verify the time to reload data but didnt work....

Comment: When you said "and make de table separated with groups" did you mean grouped style or that the `UITableView` would show the sections?

Comment: So you want to change the headers' titles at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` only gets called when loading the `UITableView` or when reloading it. So if you want to change it a runtime, you could have an `NSArray` that holds the titles for all the headers and have the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` use that array.

```
 return [YourArray objectAtIndex:section];
```

And you can modify this array wherever you want in your code. You would have to call `[YourTableView reload]` anyways to fire up the delegate and get the headers titles updated in your view.

---

I don't know if you still need the information bellow so I'll leave it here.

To reload a `UITableView` all you have to do is call `[YourTableView reload];`.

As for groups, that's a `UITableView` style. You can modify this either through IB in the Attributes Inspector in `Table View > Style > Grouped`. Or programmatically using `UITableViewStyleGrouped` in the `TableView`'s `init`.

For example:

```
YourTableViewController *foo = [[YourTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```